# PDF Viewer using HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

i need to preview .pdf files with parameters like "search spec. word" or "open page x"

Is there a PDF viewer that will work on mobile and desktop that uses JavaScript?

Comment: Don't ask for the "best" of something; it's purely subjective. I've edited your post for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and some JS algorithms to achieve what you want.

Don't use it's `viewer.html` but implement your own (or add more functionality to that page)

Comment: Is PDF.js still supported? I thought it is out datet since Moziall V. 35

Comment: Nop. `Viewer.html` is same as native firefox pdf viewer

Comment: @nagazi It was last updated 11 days ago: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js